BlueprintJS Multi-Select scrolls to top after selection
I have developed a multi-select functionality using BlueprintJS Select component. But what I observed is that when we scroll down and click on any item in the dropdown, the item is getting selected but the scroll is moving to top (getting reset) and is not staying in the position where user has clicked it.
I observed that this is happening because ItemPredicate prop is getting called unnecessarily and re-rendering the whole component even though there are no changes in the props.
Ideally ItemPredicate method should only get called when user searches some query in the search bar, but here in this case, it is being called on item select causing the component to re-render.
Note :- If I comment out the ItemPredicate, scroll position is pertained but search doesn't work obviously.
Here is the sample code. Please suggest If I am doing anything wrong
<Blueprint3.Select
itemRenderer={renderItem}
itemPredicate={itemPredicate} // This is re-rendering on item selection and hence the issue
items={groupedLeaders}
onItemSelect={(item) => {}}
>
    <Button
      minimal
      outlined
      text={"Search here"}
    />
</Blueprint3.Select>

